# Which Array did value come from

Tags: php

I have multiple arrays shown below.

```
<?php
$arrLayout = array(
    "section1" => array(

        "wXBMCLibrary" => array(
            "title" => "XBMC Library",
            "display" => ""
        ),
        "wRecentMovies" => array(
            "title" => "Recent Movies",
            "display" => ""
        )
    ),
    "section2" => array(
        "wComingEpisodes" => array(
            "title" => "Coming Episodes",
            "display" => ""
        ),
        "wSearch" => array(
            "title" => "Search",
            "display" => ""
        )
    ),
 );
```

From looking at the code I can see that wXBMCLibrary comes from within section1. Is there a way to check via php which section each thing comes from? So if I moved wXBMCLibrary to section 2 and reran the code it would show that it is now in section 2. Hope that makes sense.

I want to

```
if ( $wXBMCLibrary == "false" )
{ 
unset($arrLayout['section1']['wXBMCLibrary']);
}
```

This all works perfectly except that wXBMCLibrary could be in section2 because it dynamically moves so the section1 part in the unset function isn't accurate. I need a way to check which section it is in so that I can replace section1 with a variable defining the current section.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, by iterating over the array and compare the values/keys.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense I'm afraid.  Try explaining exactly what it is you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function which_section($array, $find) {
  foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    foreach ($value as $k => $v)
      if ($k == $find) return $key;
  return false;
}

$section = which_section($arrLayout, 'wXBMCLibrary');
unset($arrLayout[$section]['wXBMCLibrary']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in PHP don't have a `..` type thing to get at the parent level like most file systems do. To get at a record, you have to know the 'path' through the array to where the data you have is. Without that path, you'll have to rescan the array to find your data, and keep track of your path through it.